Byte order problems when getting ByteString from Word16
When I run the code:
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad
import Network.Socket
import System.Environment
import System.IO
import Numeric (showHex)
import qualified System.ByteOrder as BO
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import Data.ByteString (toStrict)
import Data.ByteString.Conversion (toByteString)
import Data.Word (Word16)



prettyPrint :: B.ByteString -> String
prettyPrint = concatMap ((\x -> "0x"++x++" ") . flip showHex "") . B.unpack

main :: IO ()
main = withSocketsDo $ do
  port <- toEnum . read . head <$> getArgs 
  newSocket <- socket AF_INET Stream defaultProtocol 
  setSocketOption newSocket ReuseAddr 1
  bindSocket newSocket $ SockAddrInet port iNADDR_ANY
  listen newSocket 2
  runServer echo newSocket

runServer :: (String -> String) -> Socket -> IO()
runServer f s = forever $ do
  (usableSocket,_) <- accept s
  forkIO $ interactWithSocket f usableSocket 

interactWithSocket :: (String -> String) -> Socket -> IO()
interactWithSocket f s = do 
  handle <- socketToHandle s ReadWriteMode
  forever $ f <$> recv handle 1024 >>= process >> putStrLn (prettyPrint msg)

process :: ByteString -> IO ()
process input = let command = B.take 2 $ B.drop 2 input in
                  putStrLn (prettyPrint)

I get the output:
0x1 0x11 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
0x80 0x5

After running uspip  --tcp-port 1024 list -r localhost as expected.
But when I replace the main function with
main = putStrLn $ prettyPrint $ toStrict (toByteString (BO.toBigEndian (fromInteger 0x8005) :: Word16))

I am getting the output:
0x31 0x34 0x30 0x38

Note I am trying to write a https://docs.kernel.org/usb/usbip_protocol.html server.
I thus I need to be able to store the command codes like 0x8005 in constants for know what commands are being received.

The problem is you're using toByteString...  This is a pretty printer, so you're inspecting the pretty printed  output; see implementation), it's just forwarding to word16Dec here, with word16Dec 0x0580 == "1408" -- (== "\x31\x34\x30\x38").
Instead of trying to build an integer and trying to convert a bytestring you could just construct the right bytestring in the first place:
-- using ByteString string literals requires OverloadedStrings
B.pack [0x80, 0x05] == "\x80\x05"


As an additional note, using toBigEndian on an integer literal makes no sense. Integer literals are already written in a big-endian style, regardless of the native byte order of the system you're on, so all you're doing is flipping the bytes if you happen to be on a little endian system.

There is a way to going from a 0x8005 :: Word16 to a Bytestring? I would prefer such way.

I'm pretty sure this has been written a milion times already, but since you're writing a binary protocol I'd just keep it clear by writing out the path from Word16 -> ByteString by hand w16ToBs w = B.pack $ map fromIntegral [w .>>. 8 .&. 0xff, w .&. 0xff]

Just checked my code and the problem is from ByteString to Word16 rather than from Word16 to ByteString, because how I am writing my code.
bsToW16 :: ByteString -> Maybe Word16
bsToW16 b = let wörten = B.unpack b :: [Word8] in
                if length wörten < 2 then Nothing else
                  Just $ (wörten!!0) .&. 0xF0 + (get wörten!!1) .&. 0xF


@Delfin yeah that's just wrong. You just want B.foldl (\w b -> w  .<<. 8 + fromIntegral b) 0. There's no situation in which you want masking in the bytestring->word conversion.

Consider using the cereal library.
Data.Serialize.Put> runPut (putWord16be 0x8005) == "\x80\x05"
True

